# open different file using C programming

Tags: c, linux, file, gcc

Hello ever one I want to ask a question about file opening.I want to write a program in which I will give a path to my main folder.main folder can contain files and and other folders which in again contain other folders and files.I want to open all the file in the loop and do some manipulation on them also I want to open only specific file for example .c extended file.Is there a built in program or function that do that? or atleast is there a way through which I can check which files are there in the folder so that I can repeatedly open them

I am using C programming linux
Thanks

Comment: GNU Simple Directory Lister: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Simple-Directory-Lister.html

Comment: How about the command [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find)?

Comment: @AlexReynolds thanks so much but is there a way to list all the files i.e. files inside the directories and so on.thanks

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks but in'st find is scripting command ?? correct me if I am wrong I want C program

Comment: `find` can find all files of certain criteria (like all files ending with ".c") and then call a program with that file as an argument: `find /my/top/path -name '*.c' -exec /my/special/program '{}' \;`. It can of course do more advanced filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save yourself a lot of work and look at [ftw() and nftw()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/ftw.3.html).  They will walk through directories and their entries , starting with the path you provide, and a call a callback function that you provide.  In your callback you can check if the file is relevant for purpose and operate on it if it is.

Also [glob()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/glob.3.html) will save you some effort if you are going to be doing a lot of filename matching.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any built-in functions for what you want to do here. But you could use [dirent.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirent.h).

```
int main(){
  DIR *dir;
  struct dirent *ent;
  dir = opendir ("c:\\folder\\");
  if (dir != NULL) {

    /* print all the files and directories within directory */
    while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
      printf ("%s\n", ent->d_name);
    } 
    closedir (dir);
  } else {
    /* could not open directory */
    perror ("");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
}
```

[Here](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1046380353&id=1044780608) you can find even more examples.

Answer (score 0):

`opendir`, `readdir`, `closedir`.
if `dirent->d_type==DT_DIR`, descend into it (recursion would help).
Take a look at the file name, figure out if you're interested.